# Any other better way to handle using Java Stream or Optional.ofNullable

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

Sometimes I gets the value as `[null]` for `List<Employee> employees`. For preventing that I does the following check

```
List<Employee> employees ….

if((employees.size()>0 && employees.get(0) == null)) {
    return Lists.newArrayList();
}
```

Like to know if there is any better way using stream or `Optional.ofNullable` for the above code

Comment: `employers.stream().filter(Objects::NonNull).collect(Collectors.toList();` should work. will filter out any non-null element and collect to a list containing 0 or more elements.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe but I need this to be checked only for first element, lets say if I get the list normal then unnecessarily it will iterate the all list and does nothing

Comment: I don't think you can get anything better than what you've got already.

Comment: Wait, are you getting `null` for the list itself or the first element?

Comment: @daniu yes but sometimes just array of one element which is null like `[null]`

Comment: @AlexMan completing the code with the `else` part could reflect a better alternative in what could be improved. Though with the current code you are just checking `[null]` and not `[Emp@1, null, Emp@3]` kind of values if that might be the case as well.

Comment: Of course, there is a better way. Fix that horrible code which returns a `List` containing `null`. Besides that, the purpose of this code is unclear. Why does it have to return a new empty `ArrayList`?

Comment: I think we should check, why is null element getting add into List, rather that put check here

Answer (score 1):

If you know that it has values in this way: `[null]`. You can also check it like below:

```java
if(employees.contains(null)) {
    return Lists.newArrayList();
}
```

Or

```java
employees = employees.contains(null) ? List.of() : employees;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just filter your list

```
employees.stream() 
.filter(Objects::nonNull)
.collect(toList())
```

Answer (score 1):

As you want to check the first element only, there might be no need to uses streams here, e.g.:

```
Optional.ofNullable(employees)
    .filter(es -> !es.isEmpty())
    .filter(es->Objects.nonNull(es.get(0)))
    .orElse(Lists.newArrayList());
```